# Throwing Checked Exceptions from Anonymous Inner Classes

Tags: java, inner-classes, nested-class

What is the best practice way of getting Exception Transparency in Java when using an anonymous inner class to run some code.

A frequent pattern that I have seen in real code is using some pseudo Runnable type interface to specify some context for some given code. The best example I can think of in the JDK is the java.security.PrivilegedExceptionAction.

```
try {
    boolean success = AccessController.doPrivileged(
        new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean run() throws Exception {
                // do something
                // read file
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = 
                    new FileInputStream(new File("someFile"));
                return true;
            }
        }
    );
} catch (PrivilegedActionException e) {
    if (e.getCause() instanceof FileNotFoundException) {
        // handle IO exception
    } else {
        // impossible no other checked exception
    }
}
```

Even though reading the code you can clearly see the inner code only throws a File not found, but we lost the benefits of checked exceptions as the caller is unaware of what exception is actually thrown. A Common bug would be to introduce code into the anonymous inner class that would thrown a new exception and the code would not force you to handle that exception.

What I want is something like what's below, is this type of behaviour achievable without a language change?

```
public interface PrivilegedExceptionAction<T,V... extends Throwable>
{
    public T run() throws V;
}
```

Comment: I think anonymous inner classes are, in general, a bad idea, mainly because they can't be reused or extended.  But this is another reason.  I'm interested in any answer too.

Comment: Take a look on http://blogs.sun.com/briangoetz/entry/exception_transparency_in_java

Comment: I have seen Brian's proposal under project lambda, unfortunately this is not available in java 6

Comment: sun.com links are dead now. The article mentioned is now here https://blogs.oracle.com/briangoetz/entry/exception_transparency_in_java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why not.  The following code worked.

```
interface RunIt < E extends Exception >
{
    void run ( ) throws E ;
}

class App
{
    public static void main ( String [ ] args )
    {
        RunIt < RuntimeException > r = new RunIt < RuntimeException > ( )
        {
            public void run ( )
            {
                throw new RuntimeException ( ) ;
            }
        } ;
        r . run ( ) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: What would you do if you need to throw more than one exception? Would you have a RunIt2<E1 extends Exception,E2 extends Exception>. I guess that is not all that bad. I would have to choose which Interface to use depending on what checked exceptions I'm expecting to throw.

Comment: If you need to throw more than one exception, there are 2 options.  (1) as you say E1 extends Exception, E2 extends Exception.  (2) You could choose E to be a super class of all the exceptions that could be thrown.  If you choose 1, then the interface might look like RunIt<E1 extends Exception, E2 extends Exception, ... , E100 extends Exception > to allow for a lot of kinds of checked exceptions.  (If there are more than you need, you can set the excess to RuntimeException.) If you choose 2 that kind of defeats the purpose of the exercise.  It is not a great solution, but it works.